# Cannot find module '.' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, es6-modules, cheerio

when I use cheerio in my project with typescript, and try to compile it by tsc.
The compiler throws an exception described below:

```js
error TS2307: Cannot find module '.' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import type { CheerioAPI, Cheerio } from '.'; 

Found 1 error in node_modules/cheerio/lib/esm/static.d.ts:2
```

This seems to be a bug in the package itself. How should I solve this problem? Thanks.

And I only use cheerio in my project like this:

```
import * as cheerio from "cheerio";
cheerio.load(content) // The type of content is string.
```

> `"cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12"`
> `"@types/cheerio": "^0.22.31"` `node v16.16.0` `npm v8.16.0`

Comment: Are you sure it's okay to import v0 of the types for v1 of the cheerio package? See [how-do-definitely-typed-package-versions-relate-to-versions-of-the-corresponding-library](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#how-do-definitely-typed-package-versions-relate-to-versions-of-the-corresponding-library)?

Answer (score 0):

Lock your cheerio version to 1.0.0-rc.10, it worked for me, or, in your package.json file change the "type" to "commonjs".